# How to mock pusher with Jest Unit test in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, pusher, vue-test-utils

I am trying to mock `pusher` in vue js projcet while writing unit test cases with `JEST`.

what's the best practice to mock `pusher` and it's `functions`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this project https://github.com/nikolalsvk/pusher-js-mock.

Then you can replace the real `pusher-js` with `pusher-js-mock` by using [jest.mock()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks).